# Choose any symbol in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing something like this

```
"... /\*start  anythingCanBeEnteredHere   end\*/  ..."
```

I need a regex that gets only the `anythingCanBeEnteredHere` part, which can be a collection of any number of symbols.

The problem is that I can't find any shortcut/flag that will choose any symbol

So far I use this regex

```
var regex = /start([^\~]*)end/; 
var templateCode = myString.match(regex);
```

`[^\~]` chooses any symbol except `"~"` (which is a hack) and works fine, but I really  need all symbols.

I've also tried this `[^]` but it doesn't work right.

Comment: Why do you need to check for any regex at all when ou want to accept every character?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "symbol", if you mean anything, that's what the dot . will match

Comment: zapthedingbat, you are so right! Stupid me, missed that one out.In my reference it says, that "." matches all except \r, \n. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
 /start(.*)end/
```

will match `FOO` in `startFOOend` and `BARendBAZ` in `startBARendBAZend`.

```
 /start(.*?)end/
```

will match `FOO` in `startFOOend` and `BAR` in `startBARendBAZend`.

The dot matches anything except a newline symbol (`\n`). If you want to capture newlines as well, replace dot with `[\s\S]`. Also, if you don't allow the match to be empty (as in `startend`), use `+` instead of `*`.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for more info.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "symbol", if you mean anything, that's what the dot `.` will match

Are you trying to do this?

```
var regex = /start(.*)end/; 
var templateCode = myString.match(regex);
```

Answer (score 5):

To match **any** character, you should not use the dot operator (`.`) because it **does not match line breaks**. To include line breaks, use `.|[\r\n]` (character or line break) or `[\s\S]` (space or non-space characters).

```js
var regex = /start[\s\S]*end/;
var templateCode = myString.match(regex);
```